# Is it ok to reask someone's non-mcve question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, minimal-reproducible-example

Suppose there is a question that is what I want to find now, while the answer looks OK but the question currently looks failed to be MCVE, eg:

[Timeline effect CSS only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76522276/timeline-effect-css-only)

I think it has only small chance that OP would come back and edit the question body to become MCVE, also I want to get other answers. Is it ok to reask the same question but in MCVE form?

Edit: I ask it because according to this:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327379/22045979

edit the existing one seems is not a good idea : no one other than OP should edit the question to become MCVE.

Comment: If you had the full editing privilege, you could just edit the existing one.

Comment: But you should not edit the original question and add code in a way that changes the OP's original intent. That is not allowed.

Comment: The basic line is: no. If you want to get more answers on a question, add a bounty to it. However, the minimum bounty (IIRC) is 50.

Answer (score 6):

If the existing question is closed for reasons looking for information/clarification and does not have satisfying answers (either as answers or even comments), it is ok to re-ask with new questions (as long as you are not the author of the original one—with your current or sock puppet account). Make sure to address all concerns already raised against that question—note that a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (formerly known as MCVE) is not required for most questions, and just including one may not be enough to resolve the close-reasons. Pay attention to attribution requirements if you re-use parts of the existing question.

In following cases a different action is recommended:

- the question closed as complete off-topic—don't re-ask on SO
- the question closed as duplicate—don't re-ask. Follow guidance on fixing/asking questions that have existing duplicates/closed as duplicate: ["This question already has answers here" - but it does not. What can I do when I think a question is not a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252/this-question-already-has-answers-here-but-it-does-not-what-can-i-do-when-i). Check out [Should I really ask the same question again if the old one was closed as a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401721/should-i-really-ask-the-same-question-again-if-the-old-one-was-closed-as-a-dupli/401960#401960)
- questions that are simply downvoted/missing answers—don't re-ask: edit the existing question if you can, and add a bounty.

**In your particular case, do not re-ask the same question.** The question already has an accepted answer which sounds like it also solves your problem, and hence doesn't need reposting. Feel free to upvote the answer if it was useful to you. If the answer there doesn't resolve your problem, follow the same guidance for fixing/asking nearly duplicate questions.